# Bridge rectifier protective resistor selection

Tags: resistors, component-selection, bridge-rectifier, inrush-current

I have a device with a supply voltage range requirement 12-24AC. The B80S bridge rectifier I am using recommends a 3.5 Ohm series resistor to limit inrush to acceptable levels. Initially I decided to go for 2 x 2.7 Ohm in 0805 (metric) package. While testing the prototype it rarely happened that one of those resistors failed when using 24VAC.

I am somewhat unsure about the single pulse peak power rating that is required for the resistors and would like some feedback.

About 400uF of bulk capacitance (calculated with respect to my load requirements) are used to smooth out the AC before hitting a 5V switching regulator.

A quick estimation, ignoring parasitics like AC transformer resistance, inductance and capacitor ESR:

At 24VAC and an assumed no load factor of 1.3 for the transformer I expect a peak voltage of

U = 24V * SQRT(2) * 1.3 = 44V

With 2 x 2,7 = 5.4 Ohm and completely discharged capacitors this leads to an inrush current of about

I = 44V x 5.4 = 8.15A.

So the dissipated peak power on the resistor would be

P = 44V / 2 * 8.15 = 180W

Having 400uF load capacitance, the pulse duration would be about

t = 5 * R *C = 5 * 5.4 Ohm * 400uF = 10ms

So I would need a 2.7 Ohm resistor with a maximum pulse dissipation of 180W for 10ms.

Maybe this is a somewhat unrealistic estimation since the parasitics will work in my favor, so I performed a simulation:

[image]

[image]

While this looks "better", this would still lead to a pulse load requirement of about 90W for 3ms. I don't know if 500uH as transformer inductance are realistic though. Since the customers will used totally different supplies this will vary anyway.

Looking at some Pulse Proof Thick Film Chip Resistor data sheets:

[image]

I would have to select at least a 2010 resistor type.

Does all this sound/look reasonable or am I way off?

Comment: For extra realism you might want to add the ESR of your caps

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Cap models have specified 0.34 Ohm which is pretty similar to the caps I am using.

Comment: excellent. I often model the transformer side of things with an actual ltspice coupled inductor set and values from just some transformer I can find on digikey or somewhere that seems roughly fitting. One could also go full berserk with http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=Transformers but that rarely adds much detail

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I haven't used LTSpice so I tried to keep it simple. However I would dig into it further if required. But judging from your comment my results seem to be reasonable?

Comment: But then you bypass those resistors with relay/switch or what? You can also put resistors on primary transformer side, the ratio and inductance would give you a help.

Comment: @Marko: No the resistors stay in series, the continuous power dissipation is fine. The transformer is not part of the device. The user just connects any 12V/24V AC or DC power supply.

Comment: Negative temperature coefficient thermistors are used for inrush limiting in power supplies. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current_limiter

Comment: @Rev1.0 Are you sure to use such cap. bank if you will after use a 5V switcher? why not use a smaller capacitor without limit resistors?

Comment: @Andyaka: True, but at 24VAC I will have maybe only 50mA continuous load current. Would an NTC really be an option for such low current, regarding the required dissipation to reduce the series resistance?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič: Smaller caps would result in too much ripple. The load is about 1W, 400uF is about whats required.